# Build XLIFF file using ng x18n in system js

Tags: angular, internationalization, systemjs

How to generate xlf file in a System JS built project?
Is there any equivalent of ng x18n command that can be run on system js project?

Comment: Please update your question with the code that you've tested.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].